# Parameter not working as hard coded value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just rewriting some SQL codes and just testing the results.  When I run the query with hard coded filters, it runs, but when I use a variable it never runs or at least to the time I'm expecting the query with hard coded filter.

Can someone please help me or explain what is wrong.

```
-- THIS DOESN'T RUN
DECLARE @PortfolioCode INT = 519 
    , @ReportDate DATETIME = '2019-09-19' 

SELECT 
    TCSELL.RemainingQuantityPerc
    , SomeVal1 = TCBUY.SettleAmountTranCcy    * TCSELL.RemainingQuantityPerc
    , SomeVal2 = TCBUY.SettleAmountSettCcy * TCSELL.RemainingQuantityPerc
    , TCSELL.*
FROM     
    dbo._Dolfin_vwTradeCost TCBUY
        INNER JOIN dbo._Dolfin_vwTradeSellRunningQty TCSELL
        ON TCBUY.PortfolioCode = TCSELL.PortfolioCode
        AND TCBUY.TitleCode = TCSELL.TitleCode
        AND TCBUY.DocNo = TCSELL.DocNo
        AND TCSELL.RunningQuantity > 0
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND TCBUY.PortfolioCode = @PortfolioCode
    AND TCSELL.ReportDate = @ReportDate


-- THIS WORKS
SELECT 
    TCSELL.RemainingQuantityPerc
    , SomeVal1 = TCBUY.SettleAmountTranCcy    * TCSELL.RemainingQuantityPerc
    , SomeVal2 = TCBUY.SettleAmountSettCcy * TCSELL.RemainingQuantityPerc
    , TCSELL.*
FROM     
    dbo._Dolfin_vwTradeCost TCBUY
        INNER JOIN dbo._Dolfin_vwTradeSellRunningQty TCSELL
        ON TCBUY.PortfolioCode = TCSELL.PortfolioCode
        AND TCBUY.TitleCode = TCSELL.TitleCode
        AND TCBUY.DocNo = TCSELL.DocNo
        AND TCSELL.RunningQuantity > 0
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND TCBUY.PortfolioCode = 519
    AND TCSELL.ReportDate = '2019-09-19'
```

Comment: What does "doesn't run" mean? What _does_ happen?

Comment: Doesn’t run means, SSMS doesn’t return an error and tries to execute but runs for a while to the point that I stop the execution.

Answer (score -1):

Please examine what is the datatype of the column ReportDate in the table or view called dbo._Dolfin_vwTradeSellRunningQty (which has the alias of TCSELL).

If the datatype is a DateTime then that should be OK. If it is a string of some sort (like Varchar or Char) then you must also change your variable @ReportDate into that datatype.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an "answer". But I think you are on the right track. Not my downvote,

Comment: @RogerA Which means what? You have solved your problem with the help of this post?

Comment: @RogerA It could be a collation issue resulting in conversion of string values. Precisely what are the correct datatypes for PortfolioCode and ReportDate in their respective views (including collation)? Another thing to examine is the Estimated Execution Plan for the 2 queries. If you see any differences this might give you a clue to the slow performance of the parameterized query.